# Quiero pasar una consulta a eloquente laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

esta es la consulta que quiero pasar a eloquent en laravel el id = '17' seria el que recibo

```
SELECT t.nombre  FROM titulos t ,empleado e,acciones_personales a WHERE a.nombre=e.id AND t.id = '17'
```

y esta es la que tengo en mi laravel

```
  $titulo = \DB::table('acciones_personales')
        ->join('empleado', 'empleado.id', '=', 'acciones_personales.nombre')
        ->join('titulos', 'titulos.id', '=', 'empleado.titulo_obtenido')
        ->select('titulos.nombre as nombre_titulo','titulos.id')->where('titulos.id',$id)->where('acciones_personales.nombre',$id)->pluck('nombre_titulo')->first();
       dd($titulo);
```

Comment: ¿tienes los tres modelos respectivos creados?

Comment: si los tengo creados

Comment: este es el error que me tira cuando ya lo quiero pasar a codigo  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `titulos`.`nombre` as `nombre_titulo` from `acciones_personales` inner join `empleado` on `empleado`.`id` = `acciones_personales`.`nombre` inner join `titulos` on `titulos`.`id` = `empleados`.`titulo_obtenido` where `1` = 17)

Comment: El método WHERE no acepta de ese modo el operador AND, puedes por ejemplo usar dos métodos WHERE para lograrlo

Comment: O usar solo un WHERE y por dentro dos arrrglos con las opciones a comprobar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en el utimo operador where que usas

```
->where('titulos.id'and 'acciones_personales','=',$id)
```

Deberia ser

```
->where('titulos.id',$id)->where('acciones_personales',$id)
```

Aunque en la sentencia original parece que no usas 'acciones personales' = $id.

Siempre puedes debuggear el query producido si al final usas `toSql()` ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql)) en lugar de first e imprimes el resultado.

Comment: ya lo compuse pero ahora me trae un valor nulo

Comment: ahi lo corregi como me dijiste

Comment: Esta parte es la que me sigue confundiendo `->where('acciones_personales.nombre',$id)` pues en tu query original hace el join de acciones via empleado no a titulo. Puede ser que este de mas?